# Geolocation fails if app sent to background

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation, gps, phonegap

I'm developing a simple app with phonegap which every 30 seconds send user current coordinates to my database via ajax call.It works very well

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
            SetLocationUpdates();
        }, 30000);
         });
```

but if the user navigates to another app(google maps app) or if I open google maps app with this code

```
<div><a href="geo:41.897096,27.036545">Open maps app</div>
```

it(sending coordinates to my database via ajax) fails because getCurrentPosition does not work maybe google maps lock it althoug my app is still work(my app and google map app work separately.Two apps work at same time.Maybe my app go background)

More specifically, it does nothing.

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(SetLocationUpdates, onError);
```

this line not execute.
 The success or error callbacks are never called, and setting a timeout does not affect this. I am using Phonegap Build to compile the app from html and javascript.
What should I do?

Comment: This should fix your problem. https://github.com/pmwisdom/cordova-background-geolocation-services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a native background geolocation solution - JS execution on the main thread gets paused when your app goes into the background.

In my experience, the most resilient solution is [cordova-background-geolocation-lt](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt). I've tested on multiple OS versions, including Android 8 and iOS 11, and this has worked consistently on all.

Comment: js code execute.ajax call or other things works.Just geolocation not work.I try other background geolocation but doesnt work...geolacation-lt is not free I can not try iy

Comment: `js code execute.ajax call or other things works`: yes, but your app process can be killed off at any time by the Android OS: i.e. not reliably. `.geolacation-lt is not free I can not try iy`: cordova-background-geolocation-lt is free for debug builds so you can try it. it only requires a license for release builds.

Comment: So you suggest me background geolocation instead of custom geolocation for performance and reliably...Thanks @daveAlden  .... I will delete custom geolocation and I will use background geolocation for testing it

Comment: @DaveAlden "You need a native background geolocation solution" in your opinion why hasn't W3C provided a Service Worker solution such as https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen ? (Apart from Transistor Software would go broke and Google's Flutter would be abandoned)

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that Firefox currently continues to work when the phone is asleep or the App is backgrounded. (I believe this is a bug)

IMHO the most appropriate and battery friendly solution relies on ServiceWorkers receiving and actioning TravelEvents from the TravelManager.

See this [Web App](https://hypocampus.applications.uwa.edu.au/travelmanager.html) for proof of how well Background geolocation fits with ServiceWorker infrastructure. All source can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Rmd3Rn8_hDNW1zSWRoXzBTclU) including a aaa_readme.txt.

Please ask W3C/IETF to standardize this and your UA vendors to implement it!